# Преобразовать формат даты в Y-m-d H:i:s

Tags: php, datetime

Есть такой формат даты `44029` что есть `17/07/2020`

Как из него `44029` сделать такой `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` ?

Такое не работает

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', 44029);
$date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$unixDate = (44029 - 25569) * 86400;
echo gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $unixDate);
```

Где `44029` ваша дата.

Или

```
$date = new DateTime("1899-12-30");
$date->modify("+".$date_in_number_format." day");
```

Comment: Первый вариант работает. А что вот за это числа 25569) * 86400 ?

Comment: 86400 - количество секунд в дне, 25569 дней между 30 декабря 1899 года и 01 января 1970 года.